# Magento 2 : Override model file (customer account)

Tags: magento2

Is their any way to override `createAccountWithPasswordHash` method from

`Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement` file ?

i tried
etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement" type="Vendor\Customer\Model\AccountManagement" />
</config>
```

Vendor/Customer/Model/AccountManagement.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Customer\Model;

/**
 * Handle various customer account actions
 */
class AccountManagement extends \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement
{
    public function createAccountWithPasswordHash(CustomerInterface $customer, $hash, $redirectUrl = '')
    {
        echo 'checkoverridecreateAccountWithPasswordHash'; exit;
    }
}
```

Getting error on setup upgrade

PHP Fatal error:  Could not check compatibility between Vendor\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::createAccountWithPasswordHash(Vendor\Customer\Model\CustomerInterface $customer, $hash, $redirectUrl = '') and Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::createAccountWithPasswordHash(Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer, $hash, $redirectUrl = ''), because class Vendor\Customer\Model\CustomerInterface is not available in /Vendor/Customer/Model/AccountManagement.php on line 10

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Class DollsKill\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor does not exist

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

add below dependency in your file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Customer\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

/*
 * Handle various customer account actions
 */
class AccountManagement extends \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    **/
     
    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    /**
     * Handle various customer account actions
     */
    class AccountManagement extends \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement
    {
        public function createAccountWithPasswordHash(CustomerInterface $customer, $hash, $redirectUrl = '')
        {
            echo 'checkoverridecreateAccountWithPasswordHash'; exit;
        }
    }
```

and check. I hope it's working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer can you please add full file code ?

Comment: I think i execution faces issues due to improper parent construct code

Comment: check updated ans

Comment: Thanks let me check it.

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: Vendor\\Customer\\Model\\AccountManagement\\Interceptor::$storeManager

Comment: Now "Call to a member function strlen() on null error

Comment: add required dependency in your file

Comment: Can i share you main original file & would you please update answer as per file ?

Comment: not working properly

Answer (score 0):

replace first argument CustomerInterface with \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface